# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'save' - Python PIL QR Code not saving

Tags: python, csv, python-imaging-library, qr-code, attributeerror

I'm a newcomer to programming so i apologize for my lack of technical ability.

I'm trying to create a qrcode generator in python, however, when i try to increment the number on the filename save, i get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sam/Desktop/QR Code Gen/run.py", line 52, in <module>
    purchase_code_fn()
  File "/home/sam/Desktop/QR Code Gen/run.py", line 32, in purchase_code_fn
    qr_code_fn()
  File "/home/sam/Desktop/QR Code Gen/run.py", line 41, in qr_code_fn
    im.save("filename"+ count + ".png")
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'save'
>>>
```

Is there anyway to rectify this?

(see below for my full code - it's still a WIP)

```
from qrcode import *
import csv
import time


active_csv = csv.writer(open("active_codes.csv", "wb"))  
void_csv = csv.writer(open("void_codes.csv", "wb"))

active_csv.writerow([
    ('product_id'),
    ('code_id'),
    ('customer_name'),
    ('customer_email'),
    ('date_purchased'),
    ('date_expiry')])

void_csv.writerow([
    ('code_id'),
    ('customer_email'),
    ('date_expiry')])




count = 0

def purchase_code_fn():
                  global count
                  count =+ 1
                  customer_email = raw_input("Please enter your email: ")
                  product_id = raw_input("Which product would you like (1 - 5): ")
                  qr_code_fn()


def qr_code_fn():
                  qr = QRCode(version=5, error_correction=ERROR_CORRECT_M)
                  qr.add_data("asaasasa")
                  qr.make() # Generate the QRCode itself
                  # im contains a PIL.Image.Image object
                  im = qr.make_image
                  im.save("filename"+ count + ".png") 

def restart_fn():
                  restart_prompt = raw_input("Would you like to purchase another code? : ").lower()
                  if restart_prompt == "yes" or restart_prompt == "y":
                      purchase_code_fn()

                  elif restart_prompt =="n" or restart_prompt == "no":
                      print("exit")


purchase_code_fn()
```

Comment: You forgot to *call* the `make_image` function: `im = qr.make_image` is simply missing the `()`.

Comment: Note that you can't just concatenate an integer and string, so `"filename"+ count + ".png"` is also going to be problematic. Convert `count` to a string there or use string formatting: `"filename{}.png".format(count)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is here : `im = qr.make_image`. You are storing into `im` the function `make_image` of object qr. As you can store functions in variables in Python, this is a valid syntax.

So, you are not calling the function `make_image`, just storing it. It should be `im = qr.make_image()`.

Answer (score 0):

After you'll implement T. Claverie answer - it is likely that you'll fail in .save() as you are concating string and integer.

Can you try to change the following line:

```
im.save("filename"+ count + ".png")
```

to be:

```
im.save("filename"+ str(count) + ".png")
```

Comment: This is a different problem though.

Comment: Yeah, i noticed and fixed that after my code ran, thank you though! (:

Comment: Thanks Martijn! I agree, my answer might solve another bug in the code... :)